# How do I remove the defaultText attribute after at least one tag is added for the tagsInput JQuery library?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

## Problem

I have a textarea with `inputTag` JS: (my js is different than the fiddle, but the fiddle will provide a MWE to display the feature in)

```
$('#box').tagsInput({
    'width': 'auto',
    'delimiter': ',',
    'defaultText': 'Enter email',
    allowDuplicates: true
});
```

I want to delete the `defaultText` after at least one tag is added to the box.
I really just want the html `placeholder` attribute functionality.  The issue with using that is that the JS and CSS replace the original text box, also replacing the placeholder.

tag library at:

https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input/tree/master/src

js fiddle at:

https://jsfiddle.net/6aa2adba/

Example of issue:

[image]

Comment: Will textarea placeholder not work for you like the jsfiddle?

Comment: Did it work for you?  The `defaultText` is the attribute that sets the placeholder.   Try changing the placeholder text, it doesn't update.  I get the defaultText attribute, I just want the `Enter Email` to disappear after you put at least one tag in.

Comment: On the jsfiddle the `defaultText` is working just like the placeholder. Everything works on it so unable to reproduce the issue you are facing. I am using Google Chrome browser.

Comment: Does the "Enter Email" text dissappear after the tag is added?  Could you add an answer with a screenshot that shows the "Enter Email" text is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the underlying data-default that is your defaultText.
You place this snippet when you want to remove the defaultText.
Check the size of your array and if all values are removed you can call this but with the correct text

[jsfiddle for inputTags](https://jsfiddle.net/bpL6rsja/1/)

```
$('#invite-emails_tag').attr('data-default','');
```

Comment: The JS fiddle doesnt seem to have the proper functionality.

Comment: I showed you how to remove the value. If you are talking about it not coming back when the list is empty, you could check in the delete event and reset it. if it is something else, please inform me. This removes the placeholder as soon as the first entry is made, valid or not.

Comment: I must've been using the wrong fiddle.  My fault it works as expected.